# How Do I Check If User Answer Is Same As Algebra Answer In Quiz?

Tags: java, algebra

I am making an algebra quiz in Java, and I want to check if the users answer is the same as the answer of the algebra equation. This is what i got already, the checking is towards the bottom. The first if statement is checking whether the 2nd number is positive or negative and calculates it. And the second if statement is trying to see whether the user answer is the same as the question answer. The problem is that Int answer cant be transferred over to the other if statement. Is there a way I can get around this? It is using an algebra equation like this: 1x + 2 = 5.

```
        int numRight = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome to your algebra test!");
    System.out.println("What is your name?");
    String name = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ok, " + name + ", how many questions do you want on your test?");
    int numQuestions = input.nextInt();

    for(int x = 0; x <= numQuestions; x++){

        int coefficient = 7;
        int num1 = 3;
        int num2 = 23;

        while((num2 - num1) % coefficient != 0){

        coefficient = (int) (Math.random()*8)+2;
        num1 = (int) (Math.random()*19)-9;
        num2 = (int) (Math.random()*90)+10;

        }


                        if(num1 > 0){
                int part1pos = num2 - num1;
                int answer = (coefficient / part1pos);
            } else if(num1 < 0){
                int part1neg = num1 + num2;
                int answer = (coefficient / part1neg);
            }

        System.out.println(coefficient + "x + " + num1 + " = " + num2);
        int userAnswer = input.nextInt();

        if(userAnswer == answer){
            System.out.println("The Answer is correct!");
            numRight++;
        } else{
            System.out.println("The answer is wrong!");
        }


    }
```

Comment: Declare answer *outside* the `if`?

Comment: The problem is that your calculation is wrong.  3x + 5 = 11 is (11-5)/3=x but you are doing 3/(11-5)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your answer integer is declared within a different scope from your boolean statements that check for answer correctness. You should declare and initialize your answer as 0 outside of that boolean statement, around where you declare your **coefficient**, **num1**, and **num2**.

Comment: thanks, but when i do that, it wont let me set the answer in the if statements and give me an error "variable answer is already defined in method main"

Comment: @SamuelWard Did you know you can set a variable without declaring it again? Hint: the line `num1 = (int) (Math.random()*19)-9;` works and doesn't have `int` at the start.